# How to solve java.lang.AssertionError: in Mockk using livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

```
it("sendEmail"){


    //viewModel.sendEmail()
   // viewModel.authInfo.observeForever(observerAuthInfo)


    run{
        viewModel.sendEmail()
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(expectAccount, viewModel.authInfo.value)


}
```

this is my code ,viewModel.authInfo.value as null i am getting how to fix this error
and here i am getting the error

```
expected:<Success(data=AuthInfo(email=testemail@gmail.com))> but was:<null>
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<Success(data=AuthInfo(email=testemail@gmail.com))> but was:<null>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
```